# How to retrieve the position of an element (image) by using Javascript instead of CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have added three pictures in my HTML and changed their position ( top and left). However, I would like to retrieve it into my javascript so I could work with it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pong</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mystyles.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id ="divGameBoard" class = "ex1">
    <img id = "imgBall" src="Media/Ball.png" >
    <img id = "imgRight" src="Media/RightPaddle.png" >
    <img id = "imgLeft" src="Media/LeftPaddle.png" >
</div>

<script src="JS/code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my html

```
var imgBall = document.getElementById("imgBall");
var imgRight = document.getElementById("imgRight");
var imgLeft = document.getElementById("imgLeft");

var ballPosisjonTop = imgBall.style.left;
var ballPosisjonLeft = imgBall.style.left;

console.log(ballPosisjonTop)
```

my css

```
#divGameBoard {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-left: -160px;
width: 320px;
height: 200px;
background-color: lightblue;
}


#imgBall {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -7.5px;
margin-left: -7.5px;
}

#imgRight {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -29px;
margin-left: 149px;
}

#imgLeft {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -29px;
margin-left: -160px;
}
```

so you can see here, i have tried to use the method style.left but it wouldn't work. and i figured it out it was bcus of top: 50% and margin-top and bottom I have done. So i wonder is there another method I can use?

Comment: Do you need `x` and `y` positions or the percentage?

Comment: @Shinji you can use also use `display: flex;  justify-content: space-between;`  to the #divGameBoard and remove img css and no need of js.

Comment: _“i have tried to use the method style.left but it wouldn't work. and i figured it out it was bcus of ...”_ - no, it was not because of that, but because via `element.style` you can only read values that were set as _inline styles_ directly on the element. You have no read access to values that are applied via the stylesheet using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `getBoundingClientRect()` method.

`imgBall.getBoundingClientRect().left`